# Arduino library: multiple definitions of a global var

Tags: c++, arduino

I know this has been asked multiple times but could not find a post relating to this specific problem:

```
# config.h
String g_ssid = "";

# webserver.cpp
#include "config.h"

bool saveConfig(String *ssid, String *pass)
{
  // Open config file for writing.
  File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/cl_conf.txt", "w");
  if (!configFile)
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to open cl_conf.txt for writing");
    return false;
  }

  // Save SSID and PSK.
  configFile.println(*ssid);
  configFile.println(*pass);
  configFile.close();  // <-- error in this line???

  return true;
} // saveConfig
```

Compile error:

```
webserver.cpp.o: In function `saveConfig(String*, String*)':
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\build9148105163386366718.tmp/webserver.cpp:114: multiple definition of `g_pass'
```

Declaring as inline is not possible as the compiler complains:

```
'g_ssid' declared as an 'inline' variable
```

Obviously `extern`ing the variable from config.h doesn't make much sense as far as the purpose of config.h is concerned. How can this be solved?

Comment: The compile error looks like it has nothing to do with the code you posted ? What's inside webserver.cpp thats defining g_pass multiple times?

Comment: Updated. I'm wondering if the definition in the header is possible at all as all answers indicate moving definition to c file or inlining. Both are not applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would *declare* the variable in the header file:

```
String g_ssid;
```

and *define* it in a cpp file:

```
String g_ssid = "";
```

That way, the header can be included multiple times without re-defining the variable.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) for more details about the difference between declaring and defining.

Comment: That means the best practice for global variables is defining them in a .cpp file, not in .h?